# ZCD SIMPLIS function block questions

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, control, flyback

I find the figure which used to do the ZCD circuit.
please see the below figure. Does anyone know what's name of U7? I can't find this module in SIMPLIS.

I would like to use this way to do the ZCD, but I need to know the name of this module.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do here? We need a bit of context like the type of converter you want to simulate, the entire figure to see the rest of the circuit etc.

Answer (score 1):

This (U7) is a monostable flip flop, sometimes called a 'one shot'. It is typically used to produce a single pulse each time it is triggered. You can be use it to debounce a mechanical switch so that only one rising and one falling edge occurs for each switch closure, or in your case to detect the zero cross point of Vds.

See datasheets for CD4098B or CD74HC221 (just two possible examples).

Comment: Hi @Josh,

Can I find this module in SIMPLIS?
Do you mean I need to do it based on CD4098B or CD74HC22?

Comment: Those were just real world examples of the chip for reference and a broader understanding. SIMPLIS has built-in models for the four common edge-triggered Flip-Flops:
D-type, S/R, J/K, and Toggle. Individual Flip-Flop documentation can be found here: https://www.simplistechnologies.com/documentation/simplis/dp_flip_flops/topics/he_simplis_flipflops.htm

Comment: Hi Josh,

Thanks.

Could you please explain why we need to use this one? 
in my figure, why can't just connect U1 output to SR directly?

Comment: @PowerJJ, you could remove the OR gate. It is only necessary if you need it. It's not clear why what the purpose was in the original circuit (buffer or delay perhaps) but the zero crossing would still function.

Comment: Hi Josh,

I mean do I need to add U7?

Comment: @PowerJJ no you do not.

Comment: Hi Josh,

I find the one shot circuit in SIMPLIS, is it the same?
https://www.simplistechnologies.com/documentation/simplis/sp_analog_functions/topics/one_shot.htm

Comment: Honestly, at this point I'm not sure what your end goal is or what your working with. If all you are interested in is zero cross detection then the logic after the detector (opamp in this case) is irrelevant.

Comment: I would like to do the ZCD detect, and I know U1 can do that, but I am still confused about why they add the one shot (U7) inthere.

Comment: @PowerJJ I wouldn’t know either without seeing the original circuit application. I would suggest ignoring that circuit you have and reading up on ZCD outside of SIMPLIS, then implement your own specific design that meets your requirements.